# Async/Await metodos que devuelven una lista

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, async-await

Trabajo con EFcore 3.1 tengo un problema al implementar métodos async/await

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<UniversalExtend>> SelectList
        (Expression<Func<Almacen, bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<Almacen, UniversalExtend>> source)
    {
        return await _almacenRepository.SelectList(predicate, source);
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<UniversalExtend>> ListarBodega
        (Expression<Func<Almacen, bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<Almacen, UniversalExtend>> source)
    {
        var listaItem = await SelectList(predicate, source).ToList();
        listaItem.Insert(0, new UniversalExtend() { Id = -1, Descripcion = "<<<Seleccione>>>" });
        return listaItem;
    }
```

En el segundo método llamo a SelectList pero no me reconoce .ToList() el mensaje de error es el siguiente:
[image: Error, Async/Await]

¿Esto estaría bien?

```
public Task<IEnumerable<UniversalExtend>> ListarBodega
        (Expression<Func<Almacen, bool>> predicate, Expression<Func<Almacen, UniversalExtend>> source)
    {
        IEnumerable<UniversalExtend> listaItem = Task.Run(() => SelectList(predicate, source)).Result;
        listaItem.ToList().Insert(0, new UniversalExtend() { Id = -1, Descripcion = "<<<Seleccione>>>" });
        return (Task<IEnumerable<UniversalExtend>>)listaItem;
    }
```

A este método ListarBodega ya no le pongo Async porque ya no tengo que esperar que me devuelva algún resultado le estoy pasando el resultado de SelectList entonces pongo solo Task.

Comment: Porque no haces que devuelva un List?

Comment: Saludos. Agrega los `using System.Collections.Generic` y `using System.Linq;`; estos en donde vayas a usar `ToList()`; desde luego asumiendo ya esta agregado como referencia en tu proyecto.